# Can't save cropped image that switched format from CIImage and UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

This is in the context of a swift app trying to save an image to Parse.com backend
In the project, I crop an original image into a square one:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageContainer: UIImageView! //Original image container
    @IBOutlet weak var dest: UIImageView! //Cropped image container
```

original image goes trough this:

```
//Crop image
    let croppedImage = imageContainer.image
    let ciImage = CIImage(image: croppedImage)
    let ciImageCropped = ciImage.imageByCroppingToRect(grabberRectangleCoordinates)
    let finalImageToUIImage = UIImage(CIImage: ciImageCropped!)

    dest.image = finalImageToUIImage as UIImage!
```

When I compare both image with println() I get very similar results:

```
//Cropped
Optional(<UIImage: 0x79e7a0b0> size {850, 850} orientation 0 scale 1.000000) 
//Original
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7992d390> size {1280, 850} orientation 0 scale 1.000000)
```

So you see that both image do exist and are similar. I see them both on screen each in their container.

Still, when I try to save to parse with:

```
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(dest.image!)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)
    var userEntry = PFObject(className:"Photos")
    userEntry["imageFile"] = imageFile
    //save code below but doesn't matter
```

It violently crash with error message:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not save file data
>   for image.png : (null)'**

What is strange and blocks me here, is that in the save code when I replace cropped container dest.image! by original image container imageContainer.image!, it function well, yet we saw with println that both image exist and are similar.

My question is: is there something during the crop process that prevents the saving to happen properly ?

(please answer in swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
Turns out that converting image to CIImage, causes problem. So this must be avoided. Thus we will convert to CGImage instead, and use another method to crop from a rectangle coordinate. Not only it doesn't cause problem when converting back to UIImage (no more nil) it makes the code simpler:

```
        //Crop image
        let croppedImage = imageContainer.image //Original image
        //CGImageCreateWithImageInRect is the function to create the cropped image. Must be a CGImage.
        let finalCroppedImage : CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(croppedImage?.CGImage, grabberRectangleCoordinates)
        dest.image = UIImage(CGImage: finalCroppedImage)
```

You can now save dest.image into Parse.com and it won't return nil.